# How to get multiple columns from a single column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column like this:

```
         Genre
Action|Crime|Drama|Thriller                 
Action|Crime|Thriller                          
Drama|Thriller                                 
Crime|Drama                                    
Horror|Thriller                                
Crime|Drama|Mystery|Thriller                   
Documentary                                    
Comedy|Crime                                   
Action|Adventure|Sci-Fi  
.....
so on.
```

what i want is output like multiple columns:

```
it generate various column of genre eg:
action  scifi crime adventure . . . . .
0       1      0     1     0  
1       0      0     0     0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.str.split`, `stack`, and `get_dummies`:

```
df['Genre'].str.split('|',expand=True).stack().str.get_dummies().sum(level=0)
```

Output:

```
   Action  Adventure  Comedy  Crime  Documentary  Drama  Horror  Mystery  \
0       1          0       0      1            0      1       0        0   
1       1          0       0      1            0      0       0        0   
2       0          0       0      0            0      1       0        0   
3       0          0       0      1            0      1       0        0   
4       0          0       0      0            0      0       1        0   
5       0          0       0      1            0      1       0        1   
6       0          0       0      0            1      0       0        0   
7       0          0       1      1            0      0       0        0   
8       1          1       0      0            0      0       0        0   

   Sci-Fi  Thriller  
0       0         1  
1       0         1  
2       0         1  
3       0         0  
4       0         1  
5       0         1  
6       0         0  
7       0         0  
8       1         0
```

Answer (score 1):

First get that one column, then do `.values[0]` on this column.
Secondly use the previously generated string, split it by | into a list.
Using `df[df[list]]` should give you the response you want.

To conclude (for a single entry):

```
genres = list(df['Genre'].values[0].split('|'))
df[genres]
```